# iOS - Twitter integration 1.1 oauth

Tags: ios, twitter

I was integrating twitter in my app. I googled and searched in stack, could not find proper steps. 
Can  anyone tell me how it works in detail.
Thank You.

Comment: See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios

Answer (score 1):

I Hope This will help you . . .

1.Add following classes to your project 
GTMOAuthAuthentication.h/m
GTMOAuthSignIn.h/m
GTMHTTPFetcher.h/m
GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch.h/m
GTMOAuthViewTouch.xib

2 . Add following frameworks
Security.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework.

3 .set  -ObjC build option for the application target's "Other Linker Flags".

4 . Then it's time for some coding .

```
import GTMOAuthAuthentication.h and GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch.h

    - (void)signInWithTwitter
    {
    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
    NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
    NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
    NSString *scope = @"http://api.twitter.com/";

    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self authForTwitter];

    [auth setCallback:@"http://www.noop.com/OAuthCallback"];

    GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;

    viewController = [[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                                 language:nil
                                                          requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                        authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                           accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                           authentication:auth
                                                           appServiceName:@"AppName : Twitter"
                                                                 delegate:self
    finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }

    - (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)authForTwitter {
    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                consumerKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY
                 privateKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET];

    [auth setServiceProvider:@"Twitter"];

    return auth;
    }

    - (void)viewController:(GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *)viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error {

        if(error)
        {
             //handle error
        }
        else
        {
            // do stuff as per your app.
        }
    }

NOte : if you get error message like "failed to validate oauth signature and token" then check you system time is correct or not .
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Download oauth Library for authotication for ios.
2) Create Account on Twitter with all Keys 
   Consumer Key ,Consumer Secrete,access key access token
   Add int into ....
3) -(void)getList{

```
OAConsumer *con = [[OAConsumer alloc]initWithKey:@"TwitterConsumerKey" secret:@"TwitterConsumerSecret"];


OAToken *p=[[OAToken alloc]initWithKey:[@"TwitterAccessTokenKey" secret:@"TwitterAccessTokenSecret"];
```

int kPageCount=10;
       NSString*   pro=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@count=%i", @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?",kPageCount];

```
    NSURL *tt=[NSURL URLWithString:pro];

    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:tt
                                               consumer:con
                                                  token:p
                                                  realm:nil
                                                           signatureProvider:nil] ; 

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init] ;        
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];

}

}
```

- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFailWithError:(NSError *)err {

```
if (err.domain==NSURLErrorDomain && err.code==-1001) {
    [self getList];
}
```

}
- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data {

```
NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSLog(@"responseBody :%@",responseBody);
```

}